# With self drilling screw should I use a drill or a driver?

Tags: drill, screws

I need to affix some sheet metal using self drilling screws like the ones below. I have drill/driver with variable torque. What should I use for drilling/driving that? At first I'm drilling, but later I'm driving, should I use some torque setting? Should I go full speed in drill mode?

I'm worried because if I go full speed I might strip the metal, and I just use some torque setting I might not be able to drill the sheet.

[image]

Comment: 1. Get scrap sheet metal. 2. Drive screws. 3. Change Settings 4. repeat 2-3 with different settings 5. Pick which setting makes you sleep better at night. 6. Update your answer with your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what drill or tool you use to set a self tapping screw, take it easy. Turn the screw at a moderate to slow speed through the entire process. Once the self tap "drills" through the metal the screw then begins to screw in. After only a few revolutions the screw will be set. If you are really spinning  the screw you can easily strip out the hole.